# Pentaho gives Unexpected End of Stream when querying a large dataset

Tags: pentaho, etl, mariadb

I have a Pentaho transform that reads several million rows of data with a Table Input step. When running with a few million it is ok. When I hit about 15 million I get and Unexpected End of Stream Exception x out of y bytes. When this occurs I have several other table inputs going to stream lookups that work fine. The input for my main stream gets no rows. My database is mariadb and my timeouts are set to 8 hours (don't ask :/). Has anyone encountered anything similar?

My query was not using an index on my date range when I had a large range. I've forced this index and still have the same problem. In my processlist the query is stuck at "Writing to net".

Comment: What is the SQL query involved?

Comment: `SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%';`

Comment: Are you running as root, or as an app user?

Comment: SELECT id, name, email FROM log_event JOIN log_details JOIN user_details WHERE log_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date

Comment: The query is edited, but that's the jist of it. My timeouts are all very high other than net_read/write.

Comment: It connects to the database as an app user

Comment: The query will run in about 2-3 mins when done directly on the database

Comment: The query is too edited.  A `JOIN` without an `ON` becomes a very slow "cross join".  If `start_date` is a constant, that is a lot different than it being a field in one of the tables.

Comment: The joins have ON's and the dates are constants, passed in as parameters.  As I said the query isn't that slow and I can run it elsewhere.

Comment: "passed in as parameters" -- Pentaho subroutine arg?  MySQL Stored Procedure arg?  Passed as a string?  As an @variable?  It _may_ be that "passing it in" is doing something that causes the Optimizer to not be as efficient in _this_ context.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- need to see what indexes are available.

Comment: @RickJames, added info about indexes and state of query.

Comment: In addition to two `SHOWs` requested, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my MariaDB connector. I changed this to a MySQL connector and it worked perfectly.